# How to extract a cracker from a wrap with many crackers, without tearing the whole wrapping?

Tags: food

This one is hard to explain, so I'll put the image first:

[image]

As you can see (can also click to see full image) I have a nylon wrap with many crackers placed very tightly inside it. I opened the wrap from above, and want to keep the other sides of the wrap intact when taking out the first cracker, but for the life of me can't do that.

How can I extract the first cracker from the above wrapping, without tearing the whole wrapping?

Comment: Can you also open it from the end?

Comment: The packaging appears to be cellophane which is more fragile than nylon. All plastics are not the same and have different characteristics. Cellophane is biodegradable and made from cellulose, not hydrocarbon materials so that it is suitable for food packaging.

Comment: @Stan as for material I really have no idea... how can I know for sure? Also, if I open from the side I'll have to remove them all and place in a container, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flatbread is brittle and breaks easily as you already know.

The object of the packaging is to get the flatbread to you in good condition. If the packaging had enough space to allow you remove one piece undamaged, it would be loose enough for the pieces knock against each other in transit and break. Most likely, experience has shown "sacrifice" packaging is optimal insofar as the product is concerned.

Sacrifice packaging is bad news as far as you're concerned because it is engineered to preserve the product by "sacrificing" the container. You are working at cross-purposes with the manufacturer.

To make matters worse, Cellophane is used which is biodegradable but it becomes increasingly brittle as it ages.

• You could try to pull one from the centre with a pair of thin tweezers or tiny tongs while vibrating the package. The vibrations may allow you to slide the first one free.

• You could try to crack one slice into pieces with a knife. That might let you get the rest of the slices free remaining intact.

• You could try first pulling two-or-three at a time by gripping the edges and, if successful, replace the ones you don't want back into the package.

• You might have to bite the bullet (so to speak) and try carefully opening the package from the end and folding it closed afterward.

• Lastly, you may have little choice but to reuse the whole cardboard container to hold the rest of the torn package you are using day-to-day. Failing that, you might have to cave-in and go with another kind of reusable container.

Comment: Thanks, you really looked into it. And solid tips as well. Couldn't ask for more. :)

Answer (score 6):

You aren't stuck with the nylon / cellophane of the packaging; you can reinforce it!

- Image 2: Apply adhesive (Scotch) tape around one end. That's shown as purple.
- Image 3: Cut the left, top, and right sides of that end of the package, to create a "door".  (You might want to tape over the "door" too, to make it stronger and more tear-resistant.)

[image]

- Open the "door" to get out one cracker, then close the door back up. You could even add another short piece of tape at the top edge of the door to secure it to the band of tape around the package.

Comment: Nice illustrations, Brett.

Answer (score 2):

Use a pair of scissors to make a clean cut instead of ripping/tearing. I keep a pair in the kitchen all the time.